# descriptive paragrapgh

Tags: punctuation

Would we use a question mark or quotations in the following sentence?

> My mom asked if we were going to carve it for Halloween and I told her
>    no we would use it for Thanksgiving.

Comment: You need to correct the typo in the title.

Answer (score 1):

As it is written neither is to be used being as this is a paraphrased statement. Now you can rewrite it to use quotations and in that case you would include a question mark within her quoted question.

> My mom asked, "(Are) we were going to carve it for Halloween?" and I told her
>   "No, we (will) use it for Thanksgiving".
>
> My mom asked, "(Are) we were going to carve it for Halloween?" and I
>   told her no, we would use it for Thanksgiving.
>
> My mom asked if we were going to carve it for Halloween and I told her,
>   "No, we (will) use it for Thanksgiving."

It really depends on which parts are paraphrased or are a summary as opposed to a direct quote.